# Replace only the head of the list in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a list like: `[[0,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1]]` and I want to replace the head of this list, which is `[0,0,0,1,0]`, with something like `[2,2,2,1,2]`, to get `[[2,2,2,1,2],[1,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1]]`. How can I do that?

EDIT:

I have this function, returning `[[0,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1]]`, I want it to return `[[2,2,2,1,2],[1,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1]]`.

```
firstfunc :: (RandomGen g) => g -> Int -> Float -> [[Int]]
firstfunc rnd n p = makGrid $ map (\t -> if t <= p then 1 else 0) $ take (n*n) (randoms rnd)
  where makGrid rnd = unfoldr nextRow (rnd, n)
        nextRow (_, 0) = Nothing
        nextRow (es, i) = let (rnd, rest) = splitAt n es in Just (rnd, (rest, i-1))
```

Comment: `replaceFirst (_:xs) newHead = newHead:xs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
change 0 = 2
change x = x

replace (x:rest) = map change x:rest
```

Comment: Can't we add it to the above function? I mean do I call replace from it or what?

Comment: You do it like I showed you in the last question....  `((replace .) .)  . firstfunc)`, or equivalently `replace $ firstfunc gen 1 0.3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general way to transform the head of a list you could create a function:

```
transformHead :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
transformHead _ [] = []
transformHead f (x:xs) = (f x):xs
```

then you could use it to transform the result from `firstFunc` e.g.

```
transformHead (map (\x -> 2 - x)) $ firstfunc gen c p
```